# Enable to read cell value from Excel to C# while

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace EXCEL_SMS
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = "C:\\Projects\\ExcelSingleValue\\Test.xlsx ";

            Application excel = new Application();
            Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
            Worksheet excelSheet = wb.Activesheet;

            // Read the first cell
            string test = excelSheet.Cells[1, 1].Value.ToString();

            // string sValue = (range.Cells[2, 4] as           Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value2.ToString();

            wb.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting error at activesheet, I want read cell value from Excel while it's open. Can anyone tell how I can achieve it? I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Error 2 'object' does not contain a definition for 'ActiveSheet' and no extension method 'ActiveSheet' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found

Comment: @Filburt Did u get my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a mistake in "ActiveSheet" please correct it will work fine, in your code it is "Activesheet"  ('s' is a small need to be Capital 'S')

```
Worksheet excelSheet = wb.ActiveSheet; //wb.Activesheet;
```

[image]

Please see the result I am getting with the same program as below, I am able to get the first Cell from test.xlsx

Comment: what have you corrected?  are you still getting error "'object' does not contain a definition for 'ActiveSheet' and no extension method 'ActiveSheet' "  of please check if your xslx file is empty or not?

Comment: i have used another code to read but my requirement is to read the cell value while excel is open . cell value is changes every second and excel sheet have to open as per client requirement to see the parameters value . So any suggestions how to do that i can really appreciate ur help